# What's a good text editor for Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm coding mostly in Javascript, HTML and CSS.

I installed the Sublime JsFormat Package. It does a lot of unnecessary highlighting. It doesn't really help me find an accidental missing curly braces or missing semicolons.

Are there any Javascript ninjas out there that find they have a good workflow?

Comment: I find [Sublime Linter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter) is pretty decent for picking up syntax errors as you write. Also supports a bunch of other languages.

Comment: Sublime Linter works great with my Python code, after specifying many PEP8 ignores. But with Javascript, are you using special indentation spacings? I wonder if there is an InteliSense system that supports Javascript core methods.